Who still gets their passports stamped in the US?
AFAIK (correct me if I'm wrong) you no longer routinely present your passport to CBP at US airports, but merely look into a camera and have your details pulled up from the flight manifest. Logically, then, passports aren't stamped.
What cohorts, however, remain required to have their passports stamped?
I'd ask the CBP, but the Info Center is useless and I don't have the email address to the Traveler Policy Division which I suspect is the responsible department.

I assume folks with a visa still need stamping? i.e. non US citizens without ESTA

Mine is only stamped if I enter at a land-border (and only on renewal of I-94).  If I fly in it is not stamped anymore.  On B1/B2 visa.

I’m not sure all airports (with international arrivals) are equipped with the kiosks etc, are they? And aren’t first time visitors supposed to see a border officer for fingerprint taking?

@jcaron For the second part, yes indeed. So perhaps those would need to present their travel document, but I'm not sure. For the first part, kiosks are no longer involved, you literally look into the camera at the booth whereby your details are pulled up

@Crazydre I mean those equipments (anything other than talking to an officer) in general… are they deployed in all ports of entry?

@jcaron AFAIK yes, at all air and sea ports of entry, but don't take my word for it.

@Akash Only foreigners who don't get an I-94 need a stamp. The one cohort I can think of is iimmigrant visa holders.
